# SATA Driver for Sony VAIO VGN-FZ240E

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, drivers, sata, sony-vaio

I'm trying to install Windows XP on a Sony VAIO VGN-FZ240E laptop so I can play some old PC games, but I cannot proceed because I am missing SATA drivers. Sadly, it appears Sony is no longer hosting any drivers for this computer:

https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/product/vgn-fz240e/downloads

[image]

I found a driver supposedly compatible with this model of laptop named `Intel(R) 82801HEM/HBM SATA AHCI Controller` on a website called "driverscape" but in general it is not safe to trust drivers from third party sites like this, so I'm hesitant to attempt to use it.

Then again, it would be a completely air-gapped computer since I'd just be playing old PC games on it, so perhaps the risk is low.

Any suggestions for what I should try?